# Event Sourcing and Importing Flat/XML Files

Tags: sql-server, database-design, domain-driven-design, etl, event-sourcing

I work at a financial company. We received millions of Flat files and xml files and import into SQL server database, No Api data in this particular system.

Should Event Sourcing be utilized for this type of system, for flat file ETL import into database? I always thought Event Sourcing was more used for front-end web applications, so we that we can keep track of all data, and replay events into a read model.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should Event Sourcing be utilized for this type of system, for flat file ETL import into database?

Taking somebody else's flat data, and trying to make from "events" out of it, is in my limited experience a fool's errand.

Tracking your processes for loading somebody else's flat data into your system by recording a history of all of the events... that *can* be interesting; but it's fundamentally like a [warehouse system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s) where you are tracking things that happen - files written to disks, transformations completed, imports completed - and creating reports.

Also entering into the equation, are you going to give the model authority over what happens next?

It's not a problem that's a great fit for a lot of investment and bespoke code (seriously, are you expecting your company to derive a competitive advantage from how awesome the ETL load process is?  or are you just building it because you can't find a reasonable one to buy?)

Answer (score 0):

Event sourcing is a special type of persistence for the write side of an CQRS architecture that better capture the state of the system without any loss. The history of events are used on the write side and also on the read side.

In your case, if you think that rebuilding the state from the stream of events before every command is better than using a flat/already-computed state then use Event sourcing otherwise don't. If you still want the history of events you could use an Event log that is used only to rebuild old read-models (in case they get out-of-sync or a BUG is identified) or to build new read-models.

Comment: Worth mentioning that ES was not specifically designed to work with CQRS, they are orthogonal approaches. ES doesn't require CQRS, CQRS doesn't require ES.

Comment: @MikeSW And how would you use ES without *any* CQRS architecture? (I don't say it would not work, I'm just curious)

Comment: Just because we use them together doesn't mean one was designed for other (on a similar note DDD and OOP are used together, but enough devs are using a functional approach to implement DDD). And there are apps (very few indeed) where you don't need a queryable model. But I've used CQRS without ES quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Event Sourcing is used to store (track) **Domain state** changes as they happen. Those xml files are basically imports. You can map those imports to internal commands which result in domain events that can be stored.
If your app is designed using ES then it doesn't matter where the commands appear from (most of the time).

If you write that import component and think about using ES specifically for that, it's not a good idea. That activity is pretty cruddy in itself, ES was meant to handle complex domain(business) models.